# Anti reverse engineering tools that are easy to set up

Tags: c++, binary, protection

I will be distributing a c++ application, and I was wondering if there was any tools available to add an extra layer of security against reverse engineering. I'm looking for a quick fix because I don't want to spend a year learning RE, I just want to focus on my application. Should I be looking at anti debuggers, packers, or what? Is there any convenient libraries to use?

I understand that nothing can stop reverse engineering, I just would like to make it more difficult if possible.

Is there anything that is free or open source?

Comment: "Hello, I am not interested in learning the hobby that this forum is for, but I'd like you to tell me how to make this hobby more difficult or impossible. Thanks."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want to learn RE, there are some free/opensource and paid tools.

For the first you probably should look [in the answers here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1792/is-there-any-simple-open-source-windows-packer).

If you feel like spending money you can find some relatively stronger packers like:
[VMProtect](http://vmpsoft.com/) or [themida](http://www.oreans.com/themida.php).

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, open-source\free packers and cryptors is your way. But please note, that  for most of them there is an automatic unpackers or extractors, both open-source and proprietary ones.

Comment: Open source is more subjective to been compromised since anyone can look at the code and reverse it.

Comment: Paul, as well as look and  alter or improve :) So I doubt Open Source products in general are more vulnerable, there are pros and contras for each model.

Comment: the ones in the linked thread don't work except maybe the delphi ones but i have no experience with delphi or compiling for delphi and I gave up trying to compile those sources